# How do I push an item in an "incomplete" row of a FlatList towards the left?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a FlatList that I wnat to use to display some items. But when a row is not completely filled with items, that item is displayed in the center of the row. I want it to align with the items above it from left to right. How would I do that?

[image]

```
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <Image source={require("../assets/temp.png")} />;
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text>Header</Text>
      </View>

      <FlatList
        columnWrapperStyle={styles.flatList}
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        numColumns={4}
      />

      <View style={styles.tableContainer}></View>
    </View>
  );
```

Styles

```
  flatList: {
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    width: "95%",
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto",
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind, I just put each item in a container/View with a view of 25% and removed `justifyContent: "space-evenly"`